# Getting bitcoin globe data

Tags: blockchain.info, cryptography

I just saw this bitcoin globe https://blockchain.info/nodes-globe?series=topBlockRelay 
It has two modes,"Online Now" and "Miners". I wanted to ask if anyone knows what the bars and colors stand for and if there are any APIs which I can get those data.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "information" being shown is effectively useless and therefor isn't made available in any consumable form. What is being shown is the GeoIP lookup of the node that a block or transaction was relayed to Blockchain.info, and the frequency at which that location appears in their database. It doesn't reveal the location of the originator of either inventory item, or provide anything worth knowing about the state of the network or its users.

http://getaddr.bitnodes.io/ shows the approximate locations of many (but not all) listening Bitcoin nodes, which is about as close to reliable data as you can get for this sort of network.

Comment: Thanks but still what the colors and heights represent?

Comment: How many items for that particular category, blocks or nodes depending what you select.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you meant by items.

Comment: A block in the case of the "blocks" view, and a "node" in the case of the node view.

Comment: Thanks , are there any APIs that shows miners like in the link in the question? and for example if USA has 1000 nodes it will have a taller bar in the globe? the globe seems to have multiple bars just for USA and in the best case I think it has devided the nodes by states not by countries.

Comment: I saw that there is a "latest_height" parameter on getaddr.bitnodes.io , but again really didn't get what it stands for. I'll appreciate if you can also help me with this. Thanks

Comment: The blockchain.info data is useless, it's not clear what they are grouping by nor is it explained anywhere. "Latest height" is talking about what block height the node was at when getaddr.bitnodes.io last saw it, and getaddr.bitnodes.io does categorize by number of nodes per country, click "more" on the left list to get a full breakdown per country.